# how to know arrangement of index of array of char without repetition alphabeticallyabout "ciberin" java

Tags: java

```
    char alphabet[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String msg = scanner.nextLine();
    char Array_of_msg[] = msg.toCharArray();
    String key = scanner.nextLine();

    char[] Array_of_key = key.toCharArray();
    char[] SortedKey = key.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(SortedKey);

    char[] result_msg = new char[Array_of_msg.length];
    int[] Array_of_indexKey = new int[Array_of_key.length];
    int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Array_of_key.length; i++) {
        for (y = 0; y < SortedKey.length; y++) {
            if (Array_of_key[i] == SortedKey[y] ) {
                Array_of_indexKey[i] = y;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int aa = 0; aa < Array_of_indexKey.length; aa++) {
        System.out.print(Array_of_indexKey[aa]);
    }
```

This code is working on String `"Hani" -> "1032"`, but not working on name like `"gamal" -> "20413"` that have two times char 'A'.

Comment: I tried your code and "gamal" gives me "21413" not "20413". It picks "1" and not "0" because you keep iterating even after a match is found.

Comment: Please provide ***several*** sample inputs (BOTH `key` and `msg`) with expected output and actual output.

Comment: What? I can't even begin to parse the question title. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an Integer Set to store what is the valid values. I mean:

```
Set<Integer> validValues = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
  validValues.add(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < Array_of_key.length; i++) {
    for (y = 0; y < SortedKey.length; y++) {
        if (Array_of_key[i] == SortedKey[y] && validValues.contains(y)) {
            Array_of_indexKey[i] = y;
            validValues.remove(y);
            break; // this is very important, without it you get 21403
        }
    }
}
```

In your implementation let's see the case, when the input was 'gamal'. Then the sorted array is 'aaglm' and the inner loop found the first 'a' two times (this inner for loop doesn't know in the second time, that it found this 'a' previously, so we should check it with 'validValues').

Comment: thnQ really helpful ^_^